# How to make a download page

Tags: php, file, redirect, download

I'm excited on how to do the download page similar to premiumpixels.com

Example - http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/custom-audio-player-skin-psd/

**If we click on "download":**

1) page reloads to url like `premiumpixels.com/download/?file=audio-player`

2) after some timeout download begins.

3) file downloads from `cdn.premiumpixels.com/uploads/audio-player.zip`

**How do I make the same? How its done on php?**

Also, I would like to send some mysql request when download page is opened, to update file downloads stats.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you looked at now? Please read the FAQ on which questions are on-topic on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript's `setTimeout` function and then redirect the browser to the download resource.

Looks like this is the source that site uses:

```
jQuery(function () {

    // get the GET variables
    var theme = getUrlVars();

    var downloadLink = 'http://cdn.premiumpixels.com/uploads/' + theme['file'] + '.zip';

    if(theme['file'])
    {
         jQuery('#downloadLink').attr('href', downloadLink);

         delayedDownload();
    }

    function delayedDownload()
    {
         timeoutID = window.setTimeout(downloadTheme, 1000);
    }

    function downloadTheme()
    {
        window.location.replace(downloadLink);
        //window.open(downloadLink,'','menubar=1,location=1,toolbar=1,width=600,height=500');
    }

    // Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
    function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }

        return vars;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

1.) User clicks on a link - e.g. `download.php?id=my-app-id`;

2.) In download.php you do your fancy mysql update stuff

3.) Then you redirect to the actual download file: `header("Location: /folder/for/downloadcontent/download.zip");`

For SEO Friendly urls use `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` file

Comment: if we redirect, why url in the browser address tab doesn't change?

Comment: Steve: browsers generally don't display the location of a file they're downloading in the location bar.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use a response of type MIME/Multipart, where you send the HTML page in the first part, and the file in the other part, then you don't need to use javascript at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Or even a simple meta tag refresh in your page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/myfile">
```